# Prolog binary tree search

Tags: tree, prolog, max, binary-tree, breadth-first-search

I've encountered this problem:

> Write a PROLOG program that given a binary tree of with integer numbers stored in the nodes. Write a
>   program that returns the maximum value stored in the tree. For example, given the input `[4,[1,[],[]],[7,[],[]]]` the algorithm should return `7`.

I guess I have to use BFS. So this is my lecture notes about BFS:

> `bf(X,Y), Y` is the list containing the elements of the tree X, as encountered in the breadth-first visit.

```
bf([], []).
bf([void | Rest], Y):- bf(Rest, Y).
bf([tree(Integer, Right, Left) | Rest], [Integer | Y]) :- 
    append(Rest, [Left, Right], Nodes), 
    bf(Nodes, Y).
```

I don't even know what all the variables mean... Would love some help.

Comment: Where do I start to solve this question? Since the task specifies that this is a binary tree, I think I need to use BFS as this is the only searching algorithm in the slides of the lecture. 

Or do you have a better suggestion?

Comment: If you don't know what all the variables mean, where did you get that code? If from class, maybe you should ask the instructor or teaching aid. Binary trees have been covered on this site many times. Try searching on this site for `[Prolog] binary tree` for ideas.

Comment: Okay. So this is what I think:

The binary tree is already given, 4 is root, 1 is Left and 7 is Right.

Now I want to search through the tree and check if each node is bigger than the current largest.

Comment: I have updated what I think the attributes mean, but I still don't understand how this can be a bfs...

Comment: I couldn't make sense of the previous code with the strange var names, but since you've edited, your question turned out to be well asked actually (except that it had no code of your own, oh well...). sorry for giving you hard time initially. it just looked all over the place, even if it weren't. :) tell your instructor though that `bf(X,Y)` in the description is wrong; it should be `bf( [X] , Y)`, as I show in the answer. happy learning Prolog, and don't hesitate to ask new questions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, the `bf/2` predicate that you show is nice and good, except the description should have been

> `bf( [X], Y)`: `Y` is the list containing the elements of a  tree `X`, as encountered in the breadth-first order of tree traversal.

Here it is again, with some longer, descriptive variable names (I normally prefer very short, even one-letter names, with description in the comments if needed;  you  probably will do so too, later, when you're more comfortable with Prolog), and some implied unifications made into explicit unifications:

```
bf(Queue, Integers) :- 
    Queue    = [],                     %% breadth-first enumeration of the empty queue
    Integers = [].                     %% is the empty list

bf([HeadOfQueue | RestOfQueue], Integers):- 
    HeadOfQueue = void,                %% empty tree in the queue,
    bf(RestOfQueue, Integers).         %% go on with the same Integers list to fill

bf([HeadOfQueue | RestOfQueue], Integers) :- 
    HeadOfQueue = tree(Integer, Right, Left),            %% a tree in the queue,
    Integers = [Integer | MoreIntegers],                 %% fill the list's head
    append(RestOfQueue, [Left, Right], ExtendedQueue),   %% extend the popped queue
                                                         %%   with Left, then Right,
    bf(ExtendedQueue, MoreIntegers).                     %% and keep going
```

It pops a node off the "agenda" queue, takes out the node's integer, puts it into the results list being built in a top-down manner, appends the node's two child nodes to the agenda's rear, and recurses. This is thus supposed to be called with `[Tree]` as the initial queue. The trees are thus considered in FIFO order, achieving the breadth-first enumeration of the tree. LIFO would get us the depth-first.

The only thing remaining is, *what* kind of trees is it fit to work on? The answer is right there in the code: it is compound terms of the form

```
    tree( Int, RightChild, LeftChild )
```

where obviously `RightChild` and `LeftChild` are supposed to be trees / compound terms of the same form, **or** ... *do you see it?* ... the atom `void`. Signifying the empty tree, most probably.

The trees that you show in your example have another structure, the one of `[Int, LeftChild, RightChild]` presumably. You just need to tweak the `bf/2` predicate to fit to your new expected data format.

We can do this  by first *generalizing* the definition, *abstracting* over the data specifics, with

```
bf([], []).                       %% implicit unifications, shorter names
bf([Empty | Rest], Y):- 
    empty(Empty),                                  %% data abstraction!
    bf(Rest, Y).
bf([Node | RestOfQueue], [Integer | Y]) :- 
    node(Node, Integer, Left, Right),              %% data abstraction!
    append(RestOfQueue, [Left, Right], ExtendedQueue), 
    bf(ExtendedQueue, Y).

empty( void ).
node( tree(Integer, Right, Left), Integer, Left, Right ).
```

All that's left   to do now is to redefine `empty/1` and `node/4` to match  *your* kind of tree encoding. This should be simple enough. It's right there in your example data:

```
              [4,
                 [1, [], []],
                 [7, [], []]  ]
```

So,

```
empty( ... ).
node( [ ..., ...., ... ] , ..., ..., ... ).
```

Having done that, we'd define

```
maximum_element(Tree, MaxElem ):-
    bf( [Tree],  TreeElements ),
    list_maximum( TreeElements, MaxElem ).
```

*at first*, but then we could fuse the two sub-goals into one, so that the picking of the biggest integer is all done during the tree traversal itself, instead of building the whole list of them first.